# How can I get array of #text nodes of the html tree

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to use all the #text elements of an html body as an array.
The rich text can have various levels so I need to get to the lowest element.
For example for the text below I'm expecting to have an array of 8 elements.

[image]

What is the name or tag or method to get the # text node?

Comment: Considering adding the HTML in your question as text.

Comment: Why would you expect #text to work? # is the syntax for selecting by id. Text isn't a 'node' in the DOM, it's the *content of a node*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recursively scan through the nodes and push the text nodes into an array.

```js
const textNodes = []

function pushTextNode(node) {
  if (node.nodeName === "#text") {
    const nodeVal = node.nodeValue.trim();
    if (nodeVal) {
      textNodes.push(nodeVal);
    }
    return;
  }
  node.childNodes.forEach((childNode) => {
    pushTextNode(childNode)
  });
}

pushTextNode(document.querySelector("#root"));
console.log(textNodes);
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <span>
    0
    <b>
      12<u>3</u>
    </b>
    <u>
      4<b>5</b>
    </u>
    <b>67</b>8<a href="#">9</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the first parent tag and use innerText attribute.

```
<script>
var text = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText;
console.log(text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|\s)/gm, ''));
</script>
```

or if you want to use jquery , you can do like this.

```
console.log($("body span").text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm, ''));
```

Comment: I've used the method in the answer below. But anyway thanks for your participation!

Answer (score 1):

```
//find the textnode like this//
const textNodes=document.querySelector("content");
//[put on a variable]//


//using this statement //
Array.from(textNodes).map((content)=>{
  //now add eventlistener//
  content.addEventListener("//event type//",functionHandler);
});
function functionHandler(e){
  //do anything what you need//
}
```

Comment: Try this block hope your problem will be solve.